# How to add custom option to wp_dropdown_categories?

Tags: categories, dropdown

I need to add a custom option to `wp_dropdown_categories`. Now, the whole wide web world haven't gotten a solution for that ... therefore I ask for a solution here … as I can't really imagine that the developers of WordPress have not considered that this would not ever be needed, right?

Comment: What do you mean with 'custom option'? An extra argument that can be passed to the function? What do you want it to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
  add_filter( 'wp_dropdown_cats', 'add_yet_another_option', 10, 2 );

  function add_yet_another_option( $output, $r ){
    $output = str_replace( '</select>','',$output ); // remove closing select tag
    $output .= '<option class="level-0" value="some-value"> Some Custom Options </option>'; // custom option. 
    $output .= '</select>'; // add closing select tag
    return $output;
  }
```

But why would someone put custom option on the category dropdown ?

Comment: It's a client asking for it ... and as you probably already know: clients are stupid ; ).

But thanks, I'll check it out.